# Downgrade GCC from 5.2.1 to 4.9 Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, gcc, blender

Because of program compatibility issues I need to downgrade GCC to at least 4.9

How do I do this? Thanks.

EDIT: The program is Blender and am trying to do GPU rendering. The specific error the console is kicking out is

```
CUDA version 7.5 detected, build may succeed but only CUDA 6.5 is officially supported.
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_52 -m64 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/home/matthew/.config/blender/2.76/cache/cycles_kernel_sm52_3A157B804910758CA7C526B5EF063D78.cubin" --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -I"/usr/share/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel" -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=75
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:76:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/host_config.h:115:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supporte
  ^
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Error: CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.`
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9`?

Comment: (And then compile your programs with `gcc-4.9` instead of just `gcc`.)

Comment: Already did, says `gcc-4.9 is already the newest version` However doing `gcc -v` or `gcc --version` still says 5.2.1

Comment: Installing `gcc-4.x` doesn't 'downgrade' gcc in the sense you are probably thinking, it just installs it as a separate executable. So unless you symlink it (or use the `update-alternatives` mechanism) you will need to invoke the alternate version explicitly as `gcc-4.9` like @fkraiem said. If your program uses a `make`, one way may be to pass a `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9` on the command line - tell us more about your program and we may be able to give more detailed advice.

Comment: Its Blender. I am trying to enable CUDA rendering. I have the CUDA tookit 7.5 and the proprietary nvidia driver version 352.68. I have added the error the console is kicking out.

Comment: What steps (commands) are you using to build it? Did you try `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9` and/or `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9` at the start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CUDA 6.5 complains about not supporting gcc 4.9 - what to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009785/cuda-6-5-complains-about-not-supporting-gcc-4-9-what-to-do)

Comment: Tried `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9`and `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9` but blender still complains even when I resinstall it. From looking at the other thread @bain posted I have to tell CUDA to use 4.9 since it is already installed. Looking at the thread I have to do  `nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-4.9` + some other stuff not specified, but what else do I have to do, otherwise without it, it just outputs `nvcc fatal   : No input files specified; use option --help for more information`

Comment: The error comes from the file `/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/host_config.h`, look in there to see what tests determine the gcc version so you may get an idea of the env variable to set.

Comment: Found it, it says:      `#if defined(__GNUC__)`
`#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 9)`

`#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!`

Answer (score 6):

Like @steeldriver suggests, you need to use update-alternatives. Exactly step 3 on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693145/installing-cuda-7-5-toolkit-on-ubuntu-15-10). Since at this point 4.9 is 4.9.3, which is not supported, you'll need 4.8.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

Remember to choose gcc-4.8 before running the installer:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

and after, to switch back to having gcc-5 by default.

(Since you're doing it to install the CUDA SDK, I'll add that if you want to test the samples, you may want to read [this](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/NVIDIA-CUDA-with-Ubuntu-16-04-beta-on-a-laptop-if-you-just-cannot-wait-775/).)

Answer (score 1):

> ***THIS ANSWER IS DANGEROUS*** as it can damage your system and the GCC libraries on your system and make your system unusable.  **Exercise caution when using this answer, and consider this a 'last resort' answer.

#### Uninstall gcc5.4

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc g++
```

Check gcc again:

```
gcc –version
```

#### Install gcc 4.9/g++ 4.9

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Checking Version:

```
g++-4.9 –version
```

#### Link to gcc g++

```
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc
```

#### Checking Version:

```
g++ –v
gcc –v
```

cited from [this blog](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/downgrading-gcc-from-5-4-to-4-9-in-ubuntu-16-04/), and my own install

Comment: This is a terrible advice

Comment: Well I read the comment after running the code. Damn my system is screwed now.